# jQuery select2 AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using the jQuery select2 plugin and trying to get the AJAX to work with my ext data which is obviously not working and I'm just wondering if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong or missing something?

*NOTE* This is only for select v3.5.2

my js:

```
$('#cliselect').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "clientprojectpopulate.php",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

html:

```
<select id="cliselect" name="cliselect" style="width: 100%;" /></select>
```

my JSON returns (which I believe is valid):

```
[{"id":"62","text":"Alberta Innovates Health Solutions"},{"id":"4","text":"Alterna Savins & Credit Union"},{"id":"63","text":"BC Patient Safety & Quality Council"}]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured out its because i was using `<select>`

It has to be an `<input>` for the ajax data to load...

```
<input type="hidden" id="cliselect" name="cliselect" style="width: 100%;" />
```

Comment: On Select2 4.0 is the other way round. It didn't work because it was an input instead of a select.

Comment: thanks for the help I had an input, changed it to a select and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 20):

The [Select2](https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax) control is updated to version 4.0. Now `input` elements are not working any longer and there should be `select` elements in place of them.

The results have also been changed to

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };  
}
```

Inside the `processResults` function you can use them like this:

```
processResults: function (data) {
    var results = [];
    $.each(data, function (index, account) {
        results.push({
            id: account.AccountID,
            text: account.AccountName
        });
    });

    return {
        results: results
    };
}
```